# Unity - player falls through objects imported from blender

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I made a simple 3d map with blocks in blender and imported it into unity. But when I put Player on it, always falls. I want to use gravity, but I don't know what components should be added to imported objects to make the player able to move on them, not falling through them.

Now I need to manually add box collider to every component which is quite annoying. Can it be done smarter and faster?

Comment: A few issues with your question(s): please accept the answer offered by Immersive as it resolves your issue; if you have a followup question, like the one you edited in, please consider creating a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the model asset in the project assets list, make sure you've checked "Generate Collider" (or similar), and apply.